# R Keras 'verbose' not showing outputs even when the verbose value is set to '1' or '2'

Tags: r, keras, tf.keras

I have been struggling to produce a printed output in my R-console for each epoch when using Keras. This is even when 'verbose' is set to a value of '1' or '2'.

Please see the following code:

```
cifar <- dataset_cifar10()
x_train <- cifar$train$x/255
x_test <- cifar$test$x/255
y_train <- to_categorical(cifar$train$y, num_classes = 10)
y_test <- to_categorical(cifar$test$y, num_classes = 10)

model <-  keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 16, kernel_size = 2, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(32,32,3)) %>%
    layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = 2) %>%
    layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = 2, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu') %>%
    layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = 2) %>%
    layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = 2, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu') %>%
    layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size =2) %>%
    layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
    layer_flatten() %>%
    layer_dense(500, activation = 'relu') %>%
    layer_dropout(0.4) %>%
    layer_dense(10, activation = 'softmax')

model %>% compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics= 'accuracy')

checkpointer <- callback_model_checkpoint(filepath = 'model.weights.best.hdf5', verbose = 1, save_best_only = 'true')

k <- model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 5, validation_data = list(x_test, y_test), callbacks = checkpointer, verbose = 1, shuffle = 'true')
```

Whenever I run my last line of code, I see no printed output for each epoch.

I am looking for an output like the following each time an epoch is completed:

```
Epoch 1/5
Epoch 00000: val_loss improved from inf to 1.35820, saving model to model.weights.best.hdf5
46s - loss: 1.6192 - acc: 0.4140 - val_loss: 1.3582 - val_acc: 0.5166
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do `plot(k)

model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test)

model %>% predict_classes(x_test)` give output?

Comment: @Isaiah Thank you, however, this is not exactly what I'm looking for; I'm trying to implement verbose such that it generates a printed output for each completed epoch.